# Laravel custom directory structure

Tags: php, laravel, directory-structure

I am attempting to create a sort of custom directory structure, my proposed structure is as follows

```
App/ - Contains all Laravel core code
Repo/ - Contains packages, each package contains Controllers, Views, Modals, Seeds and Migrations specific to that package
```

Is it possible via Composer or would it take a lot of core modification?

Controller routing in `routes.php`

```
Route::resource('account', '\Repo\Accounts\Accounts');
```

The first occurrence of accounts is the folder and the second being the class. I know I could write each directory seperetly then dump composer autoload, however when you have 30 seperate packages per app, it is a little time consuming. Am I missing something super straight forward?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with composer. Add inside of your `composer.json`:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        // ...
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "Repo\\" : "Repo"
    }
},
```

Then you can use classes inside of the `/Repo` directory, and classes in there will reside in the `\Repo` namespace.

Comment: I am needing another level of structure, if that was the case at least from what I understand I could just whack them all under the Laravel structure

Comment: then instead of putting `"app/Repo"`, just put `"Repo"`

Comment: Ah ok, that sorts the controllers out, the views are fine, just the modals, seeds, and migrations, any ideas on that?

Comment: are they just going to be subdirectories of the top-level `/Repo` directory? If so, they'll be automatically included, you just need to add the directory path to the namespace path of the classes.